# How to workout the time to get the return value

Tags: jquery

I would like to get a help with my jquery. I have got a problem with the return value for those times in the HTML elements. I'm working out on the times from between time1 and time2 how long it will last for, e.g.: 4:30pm take away 6:30pm which the return value is 2.00.

Here's a sample of what the HTML is look like:

```
<span id='time1'>4:30 PM</span> - <span id='title1'>The Scorpion King</span><br></br>
<span id='time2'>6:30 PM</span> - <span id='title2'>Gone in Sixty Seconds</span><br></br>
<span id='time3'>9:00 PM</span> - <span id='title3'>The Fast and the Furious</span><br></br>
<span id='time4'>11:30 PM</span> - <span id='title4'>The Fast and the Furious</span><br></br>
<span id='time5'>2:00 AM</span> - <span id='title5'>The Scorpion King</span><br></br>
<span id='time6'>4:00 AM</span> - <span id='title6'>New Sheer Cover Studio mineral makeup</span><br></br>
<span id='time7'>8:49 PM</span> - <span id='title7'>Tamra's O.C. Wedding</span><br></br>
```

In this case, I have a return value that it will show '-10.00' from the time1 and time2 when I work out which the return value supposed to be showing '2.00' for 2 hours. There are other values that do the same which it will confuse me what hours the time will last for. I have no problem for any other return values which I will get something like 1.00, 1.30, 2.00, 2.30..etc when I work out on a different time. I would like to work out on the time to find out how long it will last for without get the return value '-10.00', '-11.00' or whatever it is to be using something is like '1.00', '2.00', '3.00'...etc before to do something.

I have tried the code like this, but it will get the wrong return values to something like '-10.00', '-11.00' or whatever it is that it supposed to be 1.00, 2.00 or whatever.

```
function getSchedule($link,j)
{
  var widthval =  850;
  var parts = $link.split("/");
  var links = parts[parts.length-1];
  var programlength = 0;

  $.ajax({
  url:$.trim(links),
  type:'GET',
  data:'',
  success: function(data)
  {
    var $data = $(data);        
    var title1 = $data.filter("#title1").html();
    var title2 = $data.filter("#title2").html();

    var time1 = $data.filter("#time1").html();
    var time2 = $data.filter("#time2").html();

    time1 = time1.split(" ");
    var time1AMPM = time1[1];
    time1 = time1[0].split(":");
    time1= time1[0]+'.'+time1[1];

    if($.trim(time1AMPM) == 'AM' && time1<12)
      time1 = parseFloat(time1)+12;
    else if($.trim(time1AMPM) == 'PM' && time1<12)
      time1 = parseFloat(time1)+12;

      time2 = time2.split(" ");
      var time2AMPM = time2[1];
      time2 = time2[0].split(":");
      time2= time2[0]+'.'+time2[1];
    if($.trim(time2AMPM) == 'AM' && time2<12)
      time2 = parseFloat(time2)+12;  
    else if($.trim(time2AMPM) == 'PM' && time2<12)
      time2 = parseFloat(time2)+12;

      var difftime2time1 = (parseFloat(time2) - parseFloat(time1)).toFixed(2);
      var difftime3time2 = (parseFloat(time3) - parseFloat(time2)).toFixed(2);

      if(isNaN(difftime2time1))
      {
        difftime2time1=0;
      }
      if(isNaN(difftime3time2))
      {
        difftime3time2=0;
      }
      var currenttotal = 0; 
      var firstele = ((j-1)*1)+1; // how many programme i want to output in per block
      var lastele = parseInt(firstele)+1; // how many programme i want to output AFTER the firstele
      var k = 1;
      var programlength = 0;

      for(;firstele <= lastele;firstele++)
      {
        var nexttimedate = parseInt(k)+1;
        var programlength = eval('difftime'+nexttimedate+'time'+k);
        //alert(programlength);

      if(programlength >= 1.00 && programlength <= 1.29)
      {
        $('#programe'+firstele).addClass("span1hr");
        width[j]=517;
      }

      if(programlength >= 1.30 && programlength <= 1.80)
      {
        $('#programe'+firstele).addClass("span1_5hr");
        width[j]=784;
      }

      if(programlength >= 1.81 && programlength <= 1.99)
      {
        $('#programe'+firstele).addClass("span2hr");
        width[j]=784;
      }

      if(programlength >= 2.00 && programlength <= 2.29)
      {
        $('#programe'+firstele).addClass("span2hr");
        width[j]=1051;
      }

      if(programlength >= 2.30 && programlength <= 2.80)
      {
        $('#programe'+firstele).addClass("span2_5hr");
        width[j]=1318;
      }

      //sort this out--------1 hour
      if(programlength >= 13.00 && programlength <= 13.29)
      {
        $('#programe'+firstele).addClass("span1hr");
        width[j]=517;
      }  

      //sort this out--------1 hour and 30 mins
      if(programlength >= 13.30 && programlength <= 13.80)
      {
        $('#programe'+firstele).addClass("span1_5hr");
        width[j]=517;
      }

      //sort this out--------2 hour
      if(programlength >= 14.00 && programlength <= 14.29)
      {
        $('#programe'+firstele).addClass("span2hr");
        width[j]=1585;
      }

      //sort this out-------- 2 hours and 30 mins
      if(programlength >= 14.30 && programlength <= 14.80)
      {
        $('#programe'+firstele).addClass("span2_5hr");
        width[j]=1585;
      } 

      if(programlength == -10.00) //sort this out  ---- 2 hour program
      {
        $('#programe'+firstele).addClass("span2hr");
        width[j]=1051;
      }
      currenttotal++;
      pgmcontent[firstele] = eval('title'+k);
      k++;      
    }
    checksum+=j;

    if(checksuminit == checksum)
    {
      for(var ii=1;ii<width.length-1;ii++)
      {
        widthval+=width[ii];
      }

      for(var jj=1;jj <= pgmcontent.length-1;jj++)
      {
        $('#programe'+jj).html(pgmcontent[jj]);
      }

      for(var kk=1;kk <= imagecontent.length-1;kk++)
      {
        $('#image'+kk).html(imagecontent[kk]);
      }
      $("body").find('.rowSubPgm').each(function(index) {
      $(this).css( "width", widthval+"px");
      });
    }
  }   
  });
}
```

I can't post the jsfiddle to show as example, because the alert won't display when I work out on the time. However I'm happy to post my website link, so you can see the alert messages with the difference values '1.00, 2.00, '13.00', '14.00' and '-10.00'. You will know what exactly I'm talking about.

My website link:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your quick reply, most of the problems are fixed but some values are showing '-9.00', '-8.30', '-11.00'. I have no idea how to get rid it and use something like 1.00, 2.00 or whatever it is.

Here is the current code:

```
time1 = time1.split(" ");
var time1AMPM = time1[1];
time1 = time1[0].split(":");
time1= time1[0]+'.'+time1[1];

if($.trim(time1AMPM) == 'AM')
  time1 = parseFloat(time1);
else if($.trim(time1AMPM) == 'PM')
  time1 = parseFloat(time1);

  time2 = time2.split(" ");
  var time2AMPM = time2[1];
  time2 = time2[0].split(":");
  time2= time2[0]+'.'+time2[1];
if($.trim(time2AMPM) == 'AM')
  time2 = parseFloat(time2);  
else if($.trim(time2AMPM) == 'PM')
  time2 = parseFloat(time2);

  time3 = time3.split(" ");
  var time3AMPM = time3[1];
  time3 = time3[0].split(":");
  time3 = time3[0]+'.'+time3[1];
if($.trim(time3AMPM) == 'AM')
  time3 = parseFloat(time3);
else if($.trim(time3AMPM) == 'PM')
  time3 = parseFloat(time3);

  time4 = time4.split(" ");
  var time4AMPM = time4[1];
  time4 = time4[0].split(":");
  time4= time4[0]+'.'+time4[1];
if($.trim(time4AMPM) == 'AM')
  time4 = parseFloat(time4);
else if($.trim(time4AMPM) == 'PM')
  time4 = parseFloat(time4);

  time5 = time5.split(" ");
  var time5AMPM = time5[1];
  time5 = time5[0].split(":");
  time5= time5[0]+'.'+time5[1];
if($.trim(time5AMPM) == 'AM')
  time5 = parseFloat(time5);  
else if($.trim(time5AMPM) == 'PM')
  time5 = parseFloat(time5);

  time6 = time6.split(" ");
  var time6AMPM = time6[1];
  time6 = time6[0].split(":");
  time6= time6[0]+'.'+time6[1];
if($.trim(time6AMPM) == 'AM')
  time6 = parseFloat(time6);  
else if($.trim(time6AMPM) == 'PM')
  time6 = parseFloat(time6);


  var difftime2time1 = (parseFloat(time2) - parseFloat(time1)).toFixed(2);
  var difftime3time2 = (parseFloat(time3) - parseFloat(time2)).toFixed(2);
  var difftime4time3 = (parseFloat(time4) - parseFloat(time3)).toFixed(2);
  var difftime5time4 = (parseFloat(time5) - parseFloat(time4)).toFixed(2);
  var difftime6time5 = (parseFloat(time6) - parseFloat(time5)).toFixed(2);

  if(isNaN(difftime2time1))
  {
    difftime2time1=0;
  }
  if(isNaN(difftime3time2))
  {
difftime3time2=0;
  }
  if(isNaN(difftime4time3))
  {
difftime4time3=0;
  }
  if(isNaN(difftime5time4))
  {
difftime5time4=0;
  }
  if(isNaN(difftime6time5))
  {
difftime6time5=0;
  }
  var currenttotal = 0; 
  var firstele = ((j-1)*5)+1; // how many programme i want to output in per block
  var lastele = parseInt(firstele)+4; // how many programme i want to output AFTER the firstele
  var k = 1;
  var programlength = 0;
```

Do you know why some of the return values are still showing '-9.00', '-8.30', '-11.00' and how I can make the return values to be showing something is like '3.00', '3.30' and '1.00' instead of using '-9.00', '-8.30', '-11.00'?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a time starting at 11 AM finishing as 1PM your code is currently adding 12 hours to both AM and PM resulting in 13 - 23 = -10

Where time is AM it is currently:

```
if($.trim(time1AMPM) == 'AM' && time1<12)
      time1 = parseFloat(time1)+12;
```

Try:

```
if($.trim(time1AMPM) == 'AM')
      time1 = parseFloat(time1);
```

Same for time2.

You will then also need to add in a check for programmes that go over midnight. e.g. starts at 2300 ends at 0100. Easiest thing to do would be:

```
if (difftime2time1 < 0) difftime2time1 += 24; // add on 24 hours
```

Comment: You want to keep it as it is for PM. That's what is putting the times in 24 hour format.

Comment: im waiting for your answer?